# Building modified AOSP throws error (Trying to change API)

Tags: api, build, hide, android-source

```
out/target/common/obj/PACKAGING/public_api.txt:4316: error 5: Added public field android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager.PASSWORD_QUALITY_MOVEMENT


******************************
You have tried to change the API from what has been previously approved.

To make these errors go away, you have two choices:
   1) You can add "@hide" javadoc comments to the methods, etc. listed in the
      errors above.

   2) You can update current.txt by executing the following command:
         make update-api

      To submit the revised current.txt to the main Android repository,
      you will need approval.
******************************
```

So i tried to add an @hide annotation to my member variable, but it will only give me another error:

```
frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager.java:233: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class hide
location: class android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager
    @hide
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I made the mistake of using `@hide` such as `@Override`, but you have to use it in a JavaDoc comment:

```
/**
  * @hide
  */
```

Comment: see  '@hide' is used here http://code.metager.de/source/xref/android/4.0.3/frameworks-base/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java

Comment: You must read some intresting things about @hide in Android Compatibility Definition @ source.android.com/compatibility/4.0/android-4.0-cdd.pdf

Comment: In which file need to write this code ? please explain in detail how you have solved?

Comment: I have the same problem. Which is the modified file?